# Calabash Android: Is it possible to use wildcards in `query`?

Tags: android, cucumber, automated-tests, android-testing, calabash

Is there a way to use wildcards e.g. `*` in Calabash `query`?

e.g. `query("TextView text:'My name is' * ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `LIKE` to perform wildcard searches according to the [Xamarin docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/calabash-query_syntax/offline.pdf)

```
e.g., "label {text LIKE 'C*ll'}"
```

You can also use `CONTAINS` e.g.

```
  query("TextView {text CONTAINS '(sn'}")
```

or `ENDSWITH` or `BEGINSWITH`

```
   query("TextView {text BEGINSWITH 'R'}")
```

Comment: Not according to this android link http://blog.appthwack.com/testing-android-apps-on-appthwack-with-calabash-android/ which says " Wildcard queries such as query '*' are helpful in seeing what’s on the screen and how to access it when using the console."

Comment: also see http://krazyrobot.com/2014/04/calabash-android-partial-matching-with-query/ for examples of different types of query

Comment: I have been able to use partial query matches using `text CONTAINS`, `text LIKE` and `id LIKE` but I can't seem to generate any query results with `contentDescription LIKE`.

Comment: This is the error I see: `Embed is a Cucumber method and is not available in this console.`

Comment: Your thoughts? Is `contentDescription` simply not supported?